# How to change frame and axes when save plot as eps in sage

Tags: plot, sage

I always use **show** command to change some parameters

```
pic1=plot(  Thermo_Cond_Sutra(por=0.4,lamb=2)
        ,(sw,0,1)
        ,color='black'
)
pic1.show(legend_loc="upper right"
        ,fontsize=15, frame=True ,axes=False
        )
pic1.save('a.eps')
```

However, the parameters in the **show()** will not validate in the eps file I saved after the show. Is there a way to modify the parameters such as Frame=true, axes=false to the eps file?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most arguments for `show` can be already put in `plot`.

```
sage: P = plot(x, frame=True, axes=False)
sage: P.save('a.eps')
```

works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I can also put it in the **save** command. i.e.

```
pic1.save('a.eps',legend_loc="lower right"          ,frame=true
          ,axes=false
          ,fontsize=15 )
```

This is particularly useful when you have multiple plots.